# How to recommend parameters in java?

Tags: java, parameters, annotations

Is there any possible way to recommend parameters when I use the method? (Just like annotations?)

I made lots of static final String parameter for url connection and I want to know whether I use right input parameter or not when I code.

Below is my example.

```
public void myRequest(String inputParameter) {
    String requestURL = "";

    static final String ex1 = "http://example.com/xml1";
    static final String ex2 = "http://example.com/xml2";
    static final String ex3 = "http://example.com/xml3";
    static final String ex4 = "http://example.com/xml4";
    static final String ex5 = "http://example.com/xml5";
    static final String ex6 = "http://example.com/xml6";
    static final String ex7 = "http://example.com/xml7";
    // too many..
    // ....
    static final String ex125 = "http://example.com/xm125";

    if(inputParameter.equals("ex1")) {
        requestURL = ex1;
    } else if(inputParameter.equals("ex2")) {
        requestURL = ex2;
    }
    // just like this..
    // .....
      else if(inputParameter.equals("ex125")) {
        requestURL = ex125;
    }
    String requestURL = inputParameter;

    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    // below codes are unnecessary.
}
```

and I will use that method in the "main" method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myRequest("ex1"); // this!!
}
```

The point is, when I write the method "myRequest()", IDE will tell me the information about parameter (when the cursor is between '(' and ')'). The only one, that I can be noticed, is "You should write String object." not "You can use ex1 which means loading ex1.xml, ex2 meaning ex2.xml or ... ex125 meaning xm125.xml"

If my hope comes true, the result seems like this.

(Writing the methods)

```
myRequest(|); // there is cursor between ( and )
```

"What xml should I request? Umm.. there is ex1 to ex125. Ok.. ex1 means.. my hometown history.. ex2 means my school history.. and Umm.. I should use ex4 ok!"
(And I write below method)

```
myRequest("ex4");
```

I want IDE to inform me what String Parameter should I use.

Is there any possible way?

Comment: @ScaryWombat but, how? I think IDE doesn't know whether that static final String variables has relationship with input parameters....

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry I am late because of working. Could you please check my added example please?

Comment: @GhostCat
Well, I have no idea because I am newbie on here. What I did is clicking the checkbox next to your answer LOL

Comment: Oh, when I click the upper one, that didn't work with popping up some blue box, which is about feedback bla bla bla.. But, now it works. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome. You see, many things you learned today ;-) And side note: there is also that (x) icon behind comments. You can use that to remove content you created that doesn't really contribute to the question/answer. You might notice that I am using that often, too ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updates to the question, the answer is build around [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and [maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

In other words: you simply, never ever put down a list of constants like you do there; that are then "mapped" (by hard wiring in your code; as you do in your example) to some other incoming strings.

Instead: you could use an enum to hold those constants; and you could also add some method to that enum class that knows how to map incoming strings to the available enum constants.

But the main point is: you want to abandon "raw" strings. The IDE (respectively the compiler) can't help you with adding an "ext1" string as method parameter.

But when you have:

```
public enum ExUrls {
 EX1("http://example.com/xml1"), EX2("...
 ... a private constructor that takes that url string)
```

then you do:

```
void someMethod(ExURls ex) {
```

and all of a sudden, the IDE will be able to suggest the all potential ExUrl constants to you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right but you can use javadocs.

Here is an example from oracle.

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

All you need to do is type /** and press enter on top of your function then you can add details. These will show up when you hover to its function call.

In your case maybe like this

```
     /**
     * This method is very amazing it will cure cancer
     * (ex1 - hometown history),
     * (ex2 - school history),
     * (ex3 - blah blah),
     * (ex4 - what is the meaning of life),
     * ...
     * (ex125 - choose this)
     * 
     * @param inputParameter - (String) You can input ex1 up to ex125
     */
    public void myRequest(String inputParameter) {
```

but if you're looking to restrict input to ex1-ex125 only you need something else.

Comment: Thank you for helping me but, Could you check my newly added example in post please? I think there is some kind of misunderstanding about I want to do.

Comment: If it is only a guide in coding Javadocs is usually used.

Try putting this comment above public void myRequest(String inputParameter) {